# GPUs are not shown with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tested the following code:

```py
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

to check the number of GPUs on my PC, but I got the following error code:

```py
C:\Users\PRodr\Desktop>py test.py
2020-04-09 12:18:50.929587: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import initializers
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    populate_deserializable_objects()
  File "C:\Users\PRodr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 85, in populate_deserializable_objects
    generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

I tried to reinstall TensorFlow, but without success.

I installed:

- cuda_10.2.89_win10_network
- cudnn-10.2-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32
- TensorRT-7.0.0.11.Windows10.x86_64.cuda-10.2.cudnn7.6

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia driver and the cuda toolkit? Which version of python and tensorflow have you installed?

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? The error seems unrelated to the code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct/recommended way to check for the existence of GPUs is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Also, you should provide more information so as to point you in the right direction (Cuda + CuDNN + TF. Version)

Comment: I installed: cuda_10.2.89_win10_network, cudnn-10.2-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32 and TensorRT-7.0.0.11.Windows10.x86_64.cuda-10.2.cudnn7.6

Comment: What is the TensorFlow version?

Comment: tensorflow - 2.2.0rc2

Comment: Please downgrade to TF 2.1 and tell me your results.

Comment: As far as I know, TensorFlow 2.1 requires CUDA >= 10.1 but I do now know for sure if it runs on CUDA 10.2